# Custom class : center chapter titles

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I want to place the chapter header in the center position.

I am using a custom .cls file. In the class file the command is:

```
\def\@chapapp{Chapter}
```

Currently, it looks like this

[image]

I used:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{ucalgthes1}
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=1in, bottom= 1in, left= 1in, right= 1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{chapter1}
\end{document}
```

The executable files and the .cls file can be found here:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/71iezjj8xllxgrk/AAA7vqqwv_FN337d5fwCEQJ3a?dl=0

Please help me in this issue.

Comment: Welcome, please make the example compilable. Can you point us to the class? You mentioned customized. Customized by you? Then we need to see *your* customized class.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I doubt `\@chapapp` has anything to do with what you seek. In the only `.cls` file from your dropbox link, `\l@chapter` seems more interesting. Usually, redefining `\@makechapterhead` and `\@makeschapterhead` (with an additional “s” for “star” (`\chapter*`) can also be a solution, at least in most chapter-using classes I know.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there's some cleaner way, but in case of emergency you can redefine `\@makechapterhead` and `\@makeschapterhead`. Here is a dumb example; you will have to add vertical spacing and whatever you want in it. Note that you can use `\thechapter` in the `\@makechapterhead` version to print the chapter number.

```
\documentclass{uclass}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[
    letterpaper,
    top    = 1in,
    bottom = 1in,
    left   = 1in,
    right  = 1in
]{geometry}


\begin{document}

\newcommand{\customchapterfont}{%
    \huge%
    \bfseries%
}

\makeatletter

% \chapter{...}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    {%
        \customchapterfont%
        \centering%
        Chapter~\thechapter\par
        #1\par
    }
}

% \chapter*{...}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
    {%
        \customchapterfont%
        \centering%
        #1\par
    }
}

\makeatother

\chapter{Test}

Text text.

\end{document}
```

[image]